# How to reset to original values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

It looks like it keeps adding a new newHeight and a newDistance each time i click, I am trying to save original height with a global var at the top and using data to do that but i get weird results, basically i should be able to reset newDistance and newHeight to first original values as per before to run the lot with a click but it doesn't and i get new added values each time i click breaking my layout as a result:

```
talents = $(".talenti");
filter = $(".filtra");

genHeight = $("#container").data($("#container").height());

filter.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (talents.hasClass("opened")) {
        $(".nasco").slideToggle();
        $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear");
        talents.removeClass('opened');
        filter.addClass('opened');
        $("#container").css("height", genHeight);
    } else  {
        filter.addClass('opened');
    };
    if (filter.hasClass("opened")) {
        $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){
            $("#sliding-navigation").slideToggle();
            var newHeight = $("#container").height() + $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);
            var newDistance = newHeight - $("#container").height() + 22;
            $("#container").animate({height: newHeight}, 50,function(){ 
                $(".box").animate({top: newDistance}); 
            });
        });
    } 
});

talents.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (filter.hasClass("opened")) {
        $("#sliding-navigation").slideToggle();
        $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear");
        filter.removeClass('opened');
        talents.addClass('opened');
        $("#container").css("height", genHeight);
    } else  {
        talens.addClass('opened');
    };  
    if (talents.hasClass("opened")) {
        $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){
            $(".nasco").slideToggle();
            var newHeight = $("#container").height() + $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);
            var newDistance = newHeight - $("#container").height() + 156;
            $("#container").animate({height: newHeight}, 50,function(){ 
                $(".box").animate({top: newDistance}); 
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

Anyone?

Comment: So `console.log(genHeight);` always returns different results? Would I be a pain if I asked for a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) example live in action? :)

Comment: Hey Chris, just replied on the other comment and provided a live example and a explanation of what happens. Thanks

Comment: Thoughts on wrapping that javascript in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` operation? Not that it would make much of a difference, but also throw in the `type="text/javascript"` into the script tag and see!

Comment: i did, i even put it at the footer.. it just doesn't reset the height, i'm a bit stack, live example is still valid on the comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on the code I could download about 20min ago from your test site, I managed to get it working with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // placeholder to contain the original height...
    var original_height = 0;

    talents = $(".talenti");
    filter = $(".filtra");

    filter.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (filter.hasClass('opened')){

            filter.removeClass('opened');

            // toggle the wrapping, just with a zero top coordinate...
            $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){
                $("#sliding-navigation").hide();
                $(".box").animate({top: '0px'});
            });

            // reset to the original height...
            $("#container").height(original_height);

        }
        else {

            // get the original height if it's not already set...
            if (original_height == 0)
                original_height = $("#container").height();

            filter.addClass('opened');
            if (talents.hasClass("opened"))
            {
                $(".nasco").hide();
                $("#wrapNav").slideToggle();
                talents.removeClass('opened');
            }

            // toggle the wrapping with a height of the nav as top coordinate...
            $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){
                $("#sliding-navigation").slideToggle(true, function(){

                    // need the height of the nav before we know how far to move the boxes...
                    var newHeight = $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);
                    $(".box").animate({top: newHeight});

                    // set the container's new height, much like you had...
                    $("#container").height(original_height + newHeight);

                });
            });
        }
    });


    talents.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (talents.hasClass('opened')) {

            talents.removeClass('opened');

            // toggle the wrapping, just with a zero top coordinate...
            $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){
                $(".nasco").hide();
                $(".box").animate({top: '0px'});
            });

            // reset to the original height...
            $("#container").height(original_height);

        }
        else {

            // get the original height if it's not already set...
            if (original_height == 0)
                original_height = $("#container").height();

            talents.addClass('opened');         
            if (filter.hasClass("opened"))
            {
                $("#sliding-navigation").hide();
                $("#wrapNav").slideToggle();
                filter.removeClass('opened');
            }

            // toggle the wrapping with a height of the nav as top coordinate...
            $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("10", "linear", function(){

                // need the height of the nav before we know how far to move the boxes...
                $(".nasco").slideToggle(true, function(){

                    var newHeight = $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);
                    $(".box").animate({top: newHeight});

                    // set the container's new height, much like you had...
                    $("#container").height(original_height + newHeight);

                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

A few points adding food for thought:

- I simplified the multiple `if` statements to make it easier to understand and process
- I used `hide()` to avoid messy animation problems if you clicked on `FILTER` multiple times in a row
- I only adjusted the `top` coordinates of the boxes to achieve this
- I would have preferred to contain the boxes in a more general container, allowing for easier animation and management, but I understand that wordpress doesn't always give you the most room to work, so this should get you on your way!

It might not be completely what you're looking for in your animation, but it's a working  example of the code you had and should get you 90% of the way...hope this helps! :)

Comment: oh man thanks a lot, i can put a wrapper div around the boxes no problem but isotope has a very strict way to work therefore it is much better to do it this way. I don't need document.ready as I have put the code in the footer but it's making isotope no to work for some reasons: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/

Comment: Um, it seems the Isotope code has been removed...original source code went from around 550 lines of code to about 400 lines in your current code, is that normal? The Isotope script started at around line 350 in the previous code I had :/

Comment: whoops! actually, you are perfectly right, i did remove the isotope bit accidentally, put it back now. Ok it looks as it works but try to click on FILTER and then click any filter, just keep switching between filters, you will see the #container getting smaller and smaller until eventually you won't be able to see the filtered boxes. It looks like as it is not resetting. I might have to insert bits of your code in the following isotope script in the footer to say on filter click, reset

Comment: right, i see what's happening. #container is positioned absolute, so when we move boxes and nav up and down, the container heigtht remains the same, which means boxes pushed down will be cut off. container has overflow:hidden set by the isotope plugin. I did try to set it as overflow:visible but that creates other issues, that's why in my first code i was setting new #container height each time, basically i was saying the #container height should be: var newHeight = $("#container").height() + $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);

Comment: Looking at that Isotope code, I'm really not sure how the filtering occurs, but I did see this: `var newHeight = $("#container").height() - $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);` ... of course the height will continuously be reduced with this. I've updated my answer to include your original question answered with a global variable holding the height, which yields better results. I hope it gets you closer to your answer!

Comment: We might need to move these comments into chat, and also flag relevant ones to whomever is looking for help! Why do you specifically need to use `+newHeight` or `+=newHeight`? This is starting to feel like a Javascript / jQuery consultation ;)

Comment: yo! :) that's it!! it works perfectly now. I was just trying to remove what we added but then i gave up and left it to take some fresh air :)
The original height is exactly what we needed! Thank you so much. Now i need to fix the detail page, in there i have to set the position of the boxes below the content and the h2 (i know you are wondering why don't I wrap the boxes in a div? The reason is due to the plugin and its use of overflow:hidden which creates lots of other issues if set to :visible. So this is the detail page: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/directors-4/regista/marco-missano/

Comment: "This is starting to feel like a Javascript / jQuery consultation" haha :)

Comment: Haha no problem! Glad it worked out in the end! Keep coding, stay awesome!

Comment: :) thanks! I might add isotope as a tag in here, also i'm going to send the site to the isotope guy, it's pretty complex this. Basically i'm using isotope centred masonry mode and i want the logo and the nav aligned with the boxes, in order to achieve this, i have to insert the #head inside the #container which is what isotope uses, the detail page is pretty mad, as it has not just the head but also the content at the top so the height needs to be worked out with jquery and? it also has to work when we click on FILTER as we got a sub nav sliding down and changing the height..oh maaann :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using the data collection of the container element rather than a global variable i.e. at the top record the height

```
$("#container").data('height', $("#container").height());
```

then to use

```
$("#container").data('height');
```

i.e. to reset the height

```
$("#container").css({height: $("#container").data('height') });
```

I feel a bit suspicious about how the global variable is working. Worth a try maybe

Comment: i was actually going to try using data and you replied :), i did what you suggested tho, and after a few clicks between .talents and .filter i get the vertical scrollbar which means it is adding height and not resetting. Live example here, try to click TALENTI and FILTER and play with switching them, you'll see appearing a window scrollbar after few clicks: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/