# how do I get wapper to expand?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Really banging my head with this.

I am using isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html.

I have a #container set relative, in it I have a head with a top nav with hidden subnav, if i click on a link on the nav it expands the subnav. Fine. 
I have a wrapper set to relative for the boxes, these boxes are set absolutely by isotope.

The issue is that when the subnav expands, it pushes the content down but the boxes are cut off. #container uses overflow:hidden and i can't make it visible otherwise it creates other issues. I've tried so many solutions, just can't figure it out.

Comment: use jsfiddle and depict your problem,without which it's hard to imagine what your problem is -- even if we succeed in understanding what we think your saying ,it usually wont be the same problem what is actually happening.. so,jsfiddle will save both of our times.. make good use of it..

Comment: so,the subnav and the nav are all classes in the site??.. it'll be easier to judge where your going wrong with a cleaner/smaller code than on your main site.. still,do try making the `height:auto` and try fixing the `min-height` and `max-height` if you dont want it to exceed certain height or be lower than a certain height..

Comment: well, you are right about min-height, i can set the #container as min-height 100%; same for box-container. Fine. It creates a window scroll bar even if not needed tho, also how would i deal with min-height in ie? and it doesn't pick up neither margin-bottom: 20px or padding-bottom: 20px when i resize the monitor. The problem in creating a small code is that boxes have random height and i use that plugin, so it's a bit complicated to create a small example. update the live link with min-heigth suggestion see the issue? p.s. ye they're 2 classes the navs, not sure where i should put height:auto;

Comment: there are many css hacks for min-height in IE,and for your other problems -- i cant picture what your saying.. sry,i'm too lazy to check the complete structure of your site.. i scratch ur back,u scratch mine.. give me a better example to work with..

Comment: So, you're looking to have the subnav piece open on top of the content? or you're looking for a way for your isotope'd content to not hide when your subnav is expanded?

Comment: i could use z-index for my subnav, that would just be the solution, subnav will open and cover the boxes, fine, done. However, i want to push the whole content down when the subnav expands. Issue is that the boxes are cut off, tried giving min-heigth 100% to box-cotainer and to #container, it works perfectly, but a: creates a vertical scrollbar even if not needed, b: i can't have padding-bottom. In fact rigth now i gave padding-bottom to the body tag, with the padding the same amount of pixel as the head + bigger sub nav height  total value, bit dirty tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually took the #head off the #container and just set with jQuery the #head width and #head margins as the #container, even on window resize, by doing so i dont need to expand the #container when the sub nav reveals and it will just push the #container div as normal.

```
 $(function() {
   var myLeft = $("#container").offset().left;
   var newWidth = $("#container").innerWidth();
   var myRight = $(window).width() - ($("#container").offset().left + $("#container").outerWidth());
$("#head").animate({ width: newWidth, marginLeft: myLeft, marginRight: myRight }, "fast");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the wrong wrapper for the isotope'd content. You should be referencing the container for your content that you want to have sorted, in this case`.box-container` (here `var $container = $('.box-container');`. So, do that, and also remove the following from your CSS, as they are not needed:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;  /* centering won't work without a solid width and not a restriction (min-width) */
    max-height: 100%; /* remove */
    min-height: 100%; /* remove */
    min-width: 930px;
    padding: 20px 5px 40px;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: nope, #container is what the plugin uses, i have inserted my #head inside this #container so that the plugin controls the position of the head too, resulting is aligning my logo and the nav always to the sides of the boxes on window load and resize. the reason why i then inserted a .box-container around the boxes is so that by setting it to position:relative, this and its child boxes will be pushed down by the revealing subnav, if i remove the .box-container then it won't happen this

Comment: if you look at it in firebug, you will the #container having a fixed width set by isotope, that's why centering works

Comment: @rob.m you can change that container reference and use any container you like, you can't reference **your main** container to be isotope'd. The plugin automatically inserts a set of styles and **height** to the isotoped container's div that has to lay separate from your main content (this is why your boxes are cutting off). Try it first and then comeback to the question :) ..by the way, the developer of the isotope plugin is a user here in SO, email him the URL to this question so he can take a look, user: [Desandro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/182183/desandro)

Comment: i know about targetting the div but what i'm trying of doing is different infact, i want to target both the boxes and the head at the same time. Previously i wrote a whole bounch of jQuery to calculate the new sub nav and set the container new height and boxes margin top, it works ok but it creates so many other issues.

Comment: The main thing basically is to have head and boxes aligned together with isotope other wise isotope is centering the boxes (i am usig a very secific istope mode, called centered masonry) and not the head resulting not aligning the logo and the nav, and also be able to push boxes down with the subnav. Look at this i fist tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131155/how-to-reset-to-original-values

Comment: @rob.m Im not quite clear yet as to why you would want to isotope your header as well, can you expand a bit on that? According to the documentation, this is pretty straight forward, but you seem to be making it a bit more complicated then it should be. You have to separate your containers is what i believe.

Comment: Ok so:

if i have <head> and then <container> isotope centers container, but the nav won't have the same width as container how could it? if instead i insert the head inside container it calculates it properly, try to resize the browser an see what happens in my live link <head>

Comment: You can have a fluid header with plain CSS, no need for it to be isotoped, check out the documentation structure so you can see how it is all stacked.

Comment: hmmm.. are you saying to have a main wrapper with <head> and <container> in it? i bet it will cut off the boxes. I read the documentation, i'm using tis specific mode btw: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html

Comment: @rob.m You can do it with your current markup, you just need to define the proper wrapper for your isotoped content, you can't isotope your main wrapper, otherwise the problem you have now will happen. Again, check out the source of the demo so you can see how all the divs are stacked. The isotoped content is on a separate container from the main container, as it should be.

Comment: yep, i'm with you. I checked the source code many times, i so hope to be wrong on this man but what i would like you to understand is that the specific istope mode i am using calculates the distances of the columns to ALWAY be centered, therefore if i put my head outside the left logo and right nav won't align with the boxes as the margins on both sides of the screen are calculated programmatically, see what i mean? Have a look at this, i have put a wrapper around it, head is fluid and isotope is targetting ONLY the boxes, see what happens to my logo and the nav?

Comment: try resizing the screen and you will see the distances vary on the boxes from the browser sides

Comment: probably now that i think about it is to just calculate the distance form the browser sides and apply that to the header elements to achieve the desidered aligment, always

Comment: also... try to click on FILTER and then any filter item, can you see the container width changes? what happens tot he head in that case?

Comment: nope, look at your nav at the top, isn't aligned with the right boxes, try to resize the browser and you will see it even more

Comment: I had an idea tho, how about:
var newWidth = $("#container").width();
$("#head").width(newWidth);

Comment: @rob.m Sounds like a good choice, right now i don't have the time to test and help you but when i do i'll comeback to this question if it has not been answered yet. Email the original developer of the plugin along with the url to this post so he can take a look, he might be able to help you in the end.

Comment: thanks man, eventually i did that, provided same width and same margins as the container and it worked out nicely. :)